# How to upload large file into s3 bucket transfer acceleration with single pre-signed URLs using .NET SDK

Tags: c#, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net

I've tried uploading large files (files above 5 GB) using pre-signed transfer accelerated URL but failed to upload files with large file size.

I get exception from C# Console application like: "The operation has timed out"

For small file sizes (<= 100 MB) this pre-signed transfer accelerated URL works fine, and I can upload files into s3 bucket with HTTP PUT request.

Can I use the single pre-signed accelerated URL to upload file sizes above 5 GB having transfer acceleration enabled?

Note: I've to use AWS .NET SDK for generating pre-signed URL.